# How to merge up multiple algorithms in WEKA?

Tags: algorithm, weka

I've visited 
[this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nje8mblA7bs&list=PLfv5OflbrxOY6HBLIOFXJf3t8jyGW-nYl&index=11)
and got the idea of merging up multiple algorithms using VOTE, but I'm not clear about the actual mechanism about how it works. I want to understand if the first mentioned algorithm is being applied at first to the data set and then the second algorithm is being applied to the classifier we are getting from the applied first algorithm ?

Suppose I choose Naive Bayes and Bayes Net, then what is happening? Is Naive Bayes being applied to the given data set first and then we get a classifier C1 and next Bayes Net is being applied to C1 and finally it is giving final classifier as C*,
or it that at each step both of the algorithms are working and the the higher VOTED result is proceeding further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each ensemble member (or algorithm) is being trained on its own training data.  Once each of these have been trained, they are later evaluated using a specific voting algorithm.

Generally, when testing cases are presented for estimation, each of the algorithms generate their estimate, and then the voting algorithm determines how the classifier's weights are applied and assigns the best output as the ensemble estimate.

That's not to say that it always works this way.  There was one proposed model I used in the past that selected a subset of algorithms depending on the locality of the testing case in the problem space and weighted each member's vote differently.  Each voting algorithm works in a different way and Weka has a few common models that can be tried out.